# How to append anchor tag from one place to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have written as

```
<div id="sample">
....
....
<a class="uploadedfiles" href="www.google.com">File</a>
.....
.....
<div class="diagram"></div>
.....
.....
.....      
</div>
```

Now I want the anchor tag with class uploaded files should be appended to 
the div with class diagram by jQuery
The output should be as

```
<div class="diagram"><a href="www.google.com">File</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or simply

```
$('.diagram').append($('.uploadedfiles').removeAttr('class'))
```

If you have many link to append to diagram div you could use

```
$('.uploadedfiles').each(function(){
    $(this).appendTo('.diagram').removeAttr('class')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("diagram")[0].innerHTML+='<a href="www.google.com">File</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

OK..

Are you asking for something like that?

```
<div id="sample">

<a class="uploadedfiles" href="www.google.com">File</a>

<div class="diagram"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.diagram { width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000000;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = $('.uploadedfiles').attr('href');

    $('.diagram').append('<a href="'+url+'">File</a>');

    $('.uploadedfiles').remove();

});
```

Fiddle:

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/dVLjU/1/)

Comment: This is right but I want jquery which will append the anchor tag on the basis of class name "uploadedfiles" not statically like .append("<a href='www.google.com;>File</a>");

Comment: Using jQuery and `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Glad To Hear That : `this still doesn't answer the question`. Let him decide what he wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you something like this:

```
var diagram=document.getElementsByClassName('diagram')[0];
var uploadedfiles=document.getElementsByClassName('uploadedfiles');
var l=uploadedfiles.length;
for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
diagram.innerHTML+=uploadedfiles[i].outerHTML;
uploadedfiles[i].parentNode.removeChild(uploadedfiles[i]);
}
```

This code deletes every node with class 'uploadedfiles' and adds it into the 'diagram' node.

Edit: sorry, didn't notice you wanted jQuery code. I rather like the pure js-coding, so I can't help you with jQuery. But I think the other answers are correct.
This code can be helpfull for those who don't use jQuery or any other js-library ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, you just need to search by starting word uploader for each anchor.

Below are the codes:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sample">

<a class="uploadedfiles" href="www.google.com">File</a>
<div class="diagram"></div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$("a[class^='uploaded']").appendTo('.diagram');
```

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/PLNH8/

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: What do you mean by "starting word uploader"? `attribute starts with` selector? Why using such selector?

Comment: attribute starting with uploader class in this case.